# How to access action class session in another action class

Tags: struts2

How to access one action class session in another action class in Struts2?

```java
public String execute()
{
    HttpServletRequest request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();  
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
    //System.out.println(" table  "+tid);
    //Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

    Map<String,Integer> s =(Map)session.getAttribute("table"+tid);  
    if(s!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("in if");
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> en : s.entrySet()) 
    {
            System.out.println(" in tableactio ");
    }
```

Comment: Do the same thing again. What's the issue you're seeing? The session isn't for the acton class, it's for the user.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29.

Comment: Session is unique per browser, per context. If you have two different tabs opened in the same browser, on the same root context, no matter if the URLs are different (for example, two actions of the same web application), they share the same session.

Answer (score 1):

**Please Note** : Session is unique to browser not to action.

in struts2 you an get session using below code :

```
ActionContext.getContext().getSession()
```

Example: Getting userid stored in session:

```
int userId = Integer.parseInt(ActionContext.getContext().getSession()
                .get("userid").toString());
```